# ORACLE - Indexes not used in join

Tags: oracle, oracle8i

I'm having a headache understanding why my indexes are not used in one of my queries.

I've no problem with these two following queries. The first one here

```
SELECT XHHA.* , XSAIL.*  
FROM TABLE_A XSAIL,  
xxd_hist_headers_all XHHA  
WHERE  XSAIL.id  = 'XXXX'  
AND XHHA.CONTRACT_NUMBER = XSAIL.CONTRACT_NUMBER  
AND XHHA.history_flag    = 'VALID'  
AND XHHA.buff_flag       = 'N'
```

Gives me the following execution plan where we see indexes being used :

```
Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  CHOOSECost: 451  Bytes: 1 332 628 342  Cardinality: 4 087 817             
    5 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 451  Bytes: 1 332 628 342  Cardinality: 4 087 817         
        2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID APPS.TABLE_A_N1 Cost: 1  Bytes: 266 911      Cardinality: 2 999   
        1 INDEX RANGE SCAN NON-UNIQUE APPS.TABLE_A_N1 Cost: 1  Cardinality: 2 999  
    4 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID XXD.XXD_HIST_HEADERS_ALL Cost: 1  Bytes: 32 304 522  Cardinality: 136 306     
        3 INDEX RANGE SCAN NON-UNIQUE XXD.XXD_HIST_HEADERS_N1 Cost: 2  Cardinality: 136 306
```

The second request below :

```
SELECT XHHA.*, XPHA.*  
FROM   
xxd_hist_headers_all XHHA,  
XXD_POLICY_HIST_ALL XPHA  
WHERE  XHHA.CONTRACT_NUMBER = 'XXXX'  
AND XHHA.history_flag    = 'VALID'  
AND XHHA.buff_flag       = 'N'  
AND XPHA.CONTRACT_NUMBER = XHHA.CONTRACT_NUMBER
```

Gives me the following execution plan where we still see indexes being used :

```
Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  CHOOSECost: 2  Bytes: 302  Cardinality: 1             
5 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 2  Bytes: 302  Cardinality: 1         
    2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID XXD.XXD_POLICY_HIST_ALL Cost: 1  Bytes: 65  Cardinality: 1    
        1 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN UNIQUE XXD.XXD_POLICY_HIST_U1 Cost: 2  Cardinality: 2  
    4 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID XXD.XXD_HIST_HEADERS_ALL Cost: 1  Bytes: 237  Cardinality: 1      
        3 INDEX RANGE SCAN NON-UNIQUE XXD.XXD_HIST_HEADERS_N1 Cost: 2  Cardinality: 1
```

Then I write this third query, which is more or less the join of the 2 previous ones :

```
SELECT XHHA.* , XSAIL.*, XPHA.*  
FROM TABLE_A XSAIL,  
xxd_hist_headers_all XHHA,  
XXD_POLICY_HIST_ALL XPHA  
WHERE  XSAIL.id  = 'XXXX'  
AND XHHA.CONTRACT_NUMBER = XSAIL.CONTRACT_NUMBER  
AND XHHA.history_flag    = 'VALID'  
AND XHHA.buff_flag       = 'N'  
AND XPHA.CONTRACT_NUMBER = XHHA.CONTRACT_NUMBER
```

No more indexes used, full scans on 2 of the 3 tables involved :

```
Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  CHOOSECost: 9 695  Bytes: 2 014 546 788  Cardinality: 4 145 158           
6 HASH JOIN  Cost: 9 695  Bytes: 2 014 546 788  Cardinality: 4 145 158          
    2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID APPS.TABLE_A_N1 Cost: 1  Bytes: 551 816  Cardinality: 2 999   
        1 INDEX RANGE SCAN NON-UNIQUE APPS.TABLE_A_N1 Cost: 1  Cardinality: 2 999  
    5 HASH JOIN  Cost: 9 004  Bytes: 41 741 836  Cardinality: 138 218   
        3 TABLE ACCESS FULL XXD.XXD_POLICY_HIST_ALL Cost: 114  Bytes: 18 903 625  Cardinality: 290 825  
        4 TABLE ACCESS FULL XXD.XXD_HIST_HEADERS_ALL Cost: 821  Bytes: 32 757 903  Cardinality: 138 219
```

Do you see any reason why indexes are not used in this third request ?
If this has any influence, the table I renamed "TABLE_A" (for confidentiality issues) is in fact a materialized view.

Thanks for you kind answers/questions/suggestions.

(Please forgive me if editing is not optimal, first time posting here).

Comment: Might be important, this is running on an old Oracle 8i ... but there's nothing I can do about that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of us who are at least 9i and above, and have `CBO`, i.e. cost based optimizer, have less tension since CBO does a brilliant job over `RBO` i.e. rule based optimizer.

Since, you are on 8i, my suggestion is to check the `cardinalities` properly. As in performance tuning I always say, ***It's all about cardinalities***.

Please note that, a `FTS`, i.e. full table scan is not always bad. When you want to fetch more than, lets say ~10-15% or more rows, the `optimizer` would rather ***estimate*** an ***execution plan*** to randomly pick the rows from data block rather than using an `Index`. Indexes are for a purpose and not always help while retrieving data. For more in depth details, just search for "***Why isn't my index being used***".

Comment: Your answer put me on the right way with cardinalities. The materialized view on my query had just been created, and when thinking about cardinalities I noticed that no analyse had been run on it.

After running the analysis on the materialized view, the index is now correctly used and my performances are as I expected them.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. As I said ***"It's all about cardinalities"***. Good luck!